# How to pass values to controler Action from Ajax Method?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi all i have ajax where i have some data And a controller action method ...i need to send the data to the controller action method ...when i am doing this it has null values in my controller method ,can any one correct me where am i doing worng...

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#butValidateForm").click(function () {               
            UpdateMethod();
        })
    });
    function UpdateMethod() {
        var s = document.getElementById("EmployeeID");
        var selecteditem1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

        var a = document.getElementById("FromStatusId");
        var selecteditem6 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

        var data = '{"AssignTo":"' + selecteditem1 + '","Status":"' + selecteditem6 + '"}';
        alert(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ViewBug/Update/",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: data,
            success: function () {
            }
        });
    }  

</script>
```

my contoller action method

```
          [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(BugModel model, FormCollection form, string selecteditem1, string selecteditem6)
    {
        if (Session["CaptureData"] == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            model = (BugModel)Session["CaptureData"];
        }
        ViewBag.AssignTo = new SelectList(GetEmployee(), "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName");
        ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(GetFromStatus(), "FromStatusId", "FromStatus");
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_history", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.Title;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FixedById", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.LoginName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AssignedId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = model.AssignTo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Resolution", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.Resolution;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =model.Status;
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            string StrFilePath = string.Empty;
            foreach (BugAttachment objList in model.ListFile)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StrFilePath))
                {
                    fileName = objList.AttachmentName;
                    StrFilePath = objList.AttachmentUrl;
                }
                else
                {
                    fileName = fileName + "," + objList.AttachmentName;
                    StrFilePath = StrFilePath + "," + objList.AttachmentUrl;
                }
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AttachmentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BugAttachmentUrl", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = StrFilePath;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AttachedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.LoginName;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        return View("Edit");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#butValidateForm").click(function () {               
            UpdateMethod();
        })
    });
    function UpdateMethod() {
        var s = document.getElementById("EmployeeID");
        var selecteditem1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

        var a = document.getElementById("FromStatusId");
        var selecteditem6 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

       // var data = '{AssignTo:' + selecteditem1 + '}';
       // alert(data);
        var AssignTo;
        var Title;
        Title=$("#Title").val();
        var FixedBy;
        FixedBy = $("#LoginName").val();
        var Resolution;
        Resolution = $("#Resolution").val();
        var Status;
        Status = $("#FromStatusId").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ViewBug/Update/",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: {AssignTo:selecteditem1,Title:Title,FixedBy:FixedBy,Resolution:Resolution,Status:Status},
            success: function () {
            }
        });
    }



</script>
```

Comment: hey, i don't 'get this'. the original question by your curious namesake asks about values for AssignTo and status. this then goes off on a tangent and answers a completely different 'issue'. hmmm - amazing number of accepted answers that you've supplied to the other anil :0. lol, be careful

Comment: Have to agree with Jim here after having a quick look through if your answering your own questions after asking other people to fix it for you in order to get reputation that is completely unacceptable and goes against the whole point of this site. Please take some time to consider those of us who go out of our way to offer help in return for something as "petty" as an accepted answer or an up voted answer.

Comment: You could, in the future .. just accept the answer that helped you the most. If you want to continue to receive help here, you really need to learn how to work with, and within our community.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
public ActionResult Update(BugModel model, FormCollection form, string selecteditem1, string selecteditem6)
```

give this a try:

```
public ActionResult Update(BugModel model, FormCollection form, string AssignTo, string Status)
```

You need to use the names of the property you have used in the object your sending back as you have named them AssignTo and Status. Hope this helps.

Edit:

Try sending the object like this:

```
var data ={};
data.AssignTo = selectedvalue1;
data.Status = selectedvalue6;
```

See if that makes any difference. If your still having issues can you inspect the request in firebug/developer tools?

Comment: ..still i get only the null value

Comment: henry - I think we're being 'duped' here, see my comment above (on `accepted' answer). the answer by 'anil- to 'anil' is quite curious. even more curious is the fact that 'anil' has answered several of 'anils' questions after being given prompts by other posters. fun stuff - watch soon for one of the display name of one of the 'anils' being changed to throw the dogs off :-)

Comment: @jim - I think your right, very fishy. Very disappointing that people feel the need to pad their accounts out by fleecing us into answering it. The thing that points to it for me is exactly what you posted, suddenly and magically fixing a "problem" that was not posted in the original question nor mentioned in any followup posts.  Ill be sure to keep clear of helping Anil again, thanks Jim.

Comment: I have flagged the question to moderators with a message describing what you originally saw (and me with follow ups) describing the pattern of discrepancies.

Comment: henry, thanks, your actions are gonna benefit all. btw, bumped you a +1 :0 and anil got -1'd too

Comment: Thanks Jim, I've already up voted you and down voted him but unfortunately he +1'd from both his accounts too.

Comment: henry, i gorra find better stuff to do with my time - get out more lolz.. `interesting stuff` tho.

Comment: henry, looks like your flag to the moderators worked, see: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1206468/anil?tab=reputation well done

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15575/discussion-between-henry-garle-and-jim-tollan)

Comment: Well that all happened very quickly, brilliant! Good work on spotting that! Perhaps neither of us should have been bothered but reputation is a driver for this site so becoming a little worked up over someone cheating is only natural :P Nice work and enjoy the nice weather!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var data = { AssignTo: selecteditem1, Status: selecteditem6 };
```

also, as per Henry's answer, use the signature:

```
public ActionResult Update(BugModel model, 
              FormCollection form, 
              string AssignTo, 
              string Status)
```

tho, you should of course be able to get both the required values from the `form[]` collection, given that you are doing an `HttpPost` behind the scenes:

(i.e. `var assignTo = form["AssignTo"];` etc).

**[Edit]** - out of curiousity, can I ask why you mix and match jquery syntax with more traditional javascript object syntax. one example being where you get the value of the `EmployeeID` option?? why not just use `var selecteditem1 = $('#EmployeeID').val();`.

I also notice the ViewBag object getting updated in your `HttpPost` action. Are you expecting to be able to use that on returning to the view -surely not (not in terms of the ajax request anyway). A quick explanation for my curiousity would be great. In my opinion, you are trying to do too much with this action (sure, keep it DRY - but) and I'm fearful that you'll end up getting into a corner with the number of different entry points you appear to be building up. I'd suggest a gentle rewind, just to keep things a little more focussed and each action having a single responsibility.